# Tooltips and autocomplete not working in React

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem in Visual Studio, more specifically with a react project. I don't get tooltips and autocomplete doesn't work, and autoimport doesn't work either. Also native functions of react are not displayed. For example, when you type useState, nothing is imported and no tooltips come out. What is the reason for this and how can it be corrected?

[image]

```js
function App() {
   return (
     <div classname="App">
        <Hell ??
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Component is not imported here

[image]

```js
function App() {
   return (

     useStat ?!

     <div classname="App">
    <Hello/>
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;
```

Function hints not coming out

Answer (score 0):

VS Code now handles this natively via a jsconfig.json and the JavaScript Language Service.

Create the file jsconfig.json at your project root and make sure to set checkJs to true:

Creating a JS Config file, allows Visual Studio to treat the folder as an Explicit Project. Without it, JS files opened in VS Code are treated as independent units, and there is no common project context between any two files.

[Here](https://medium.com/@lukehenryotwell/getting-vscode-auto-import-to-work-with-react-e1f9eadadd66) you can find more info.

Comment: I tried it didn't help

Comment: You are using useState in return of the function component which is not allowed. and also can you show me the Hello file to how you defined it?

Comment: function Hello() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

export default Hello;
Here's what's in the Hello component

Comment: Well, the only problem is with your JS and Reactjs related configs in VS Code. so, i would suggest reading this article https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig